# What is a generic way to "pass" the data from Spring FORM to DAO?

Tags: java, database, jsp, spring-mvc, dao

I am implementing a basic login form in **Spring Web MVC Framework**.
My goal is the following:

1. Get the ***username*** and ***password*** from a user
2. Process it i.e. find out if username and password
   are **matching** those from a DB
3. Return response - login SUCCESSFUL or FAILURE

I successfully obtain all the information from a user with my controller but unfortunately  I get stuck at the second point because I don't know exactly how is 
Spring dealing with such situations.

I imagine in this way: **DAO** is an **interface** which is responsible to transfer data from a form on one side and the DB on the otherside. Everything else is MAGIC for me at this point.

Please **enlighten me**!

### -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

*login.jsp*

---

```jsp
<!-- code -->
<div class="content">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="username">Username</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="username" /></td>
                    <td><form:errors path="username" cssClass="error"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="password">Password</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="password" /></td>
                    <td><form:errors path="password" cssClass="error"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>                
</div>
<!-- code -->
```

*FormDao.java*

---

```java
package si.src.dataAccess;

import si.src.forms.Obrazec;

public interface FormDao {

    /* DAO methods */
    public void saveForm(Obrazec obrazec);

}
```

*FormDaoImpl.java*

---

```java
package si.src.dataAccess;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import si.src.forms.Obrazec;

@Repository
public class FormDaoImpl implements FormDao{

    public void saveForm(Obrazec obrazec) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    }

}
```

==================================================================================

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use Spring Security, which handles all this for you. It even contains DB authentification.

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-using-database/

Don't reinvent the wheel ;-)

Comment: markusw thank you for your recommandation. Of course this is essential if you have a login form. But besides login form I have several other forms to handle in a same way. Do you have an idea how can I proceed in this case? Thank you

Comment: just inject your dao into your controller. Use the ModelAndView obejct and bind the values to your input fields. When the request hits the controller the ModelAndView object will be passed and you can access the values typed into the inputfields... http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-3-mvc-handling-forms/

Comment: Or you can use the HTTP way and use standard GET or POST parameters and map them in your controller to the approriate method http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch16s11.html

Comment: Yes, that's true, but as far as I am concerned this is not a very elegant solution if you have a very big form to pass. Correct me if I am wrong.